# I cant push array into a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, controller, schema, mongoose

This is my controller, one form send here the data:

```
   exports.addrepair = function(req, res, next){
        Person.findById( req.body.id, function (err, Person) {
               Person.update({id: req.body.id},
                                {$pushAll: {
                                       problem: req.body.problem
                                  , solution:    req.body.solution
                                  , date_on:  Date.now()
                                   }}
                ,{upsert:true},function(err){
                    if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                    }else{
                            console.log("Added");
                    }
                })
        })
    }
```

the schema is:

```
 var Person = new Schema ({
      name: String,
      Repair: [
        problem: String,
        solution: String,
        date_on: Date
      ]
    })
```

and cant push any repair to Person. With console.log i can see all works but not the push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.addrepair = function(req, res, next) {
  //The Person.findById you had here was unnecessary/useless
  Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id,
    {
      Repair: {
        $push: {
          problem: req.body.problem,
          solution: req.body.solution,
          date_on:  Date.now()
        }
      }
    },
    //You don't want an upsert here
    function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log("Added");
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thaks, but dont works, only push the first time and only create de id not the problem not solution and not de date_on

Comment: Well, let's talk details. The schema you posted isn't even valid javascript (you probably omitted curly braces inside the Repair array). You take the care and effort to post realistic snippets that you have actually run, and maybe I'll try to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me now. Thanks Peter Lyons

```
Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id,                           
       { $push: 
         { repair: 
           { problem: req.body.problem
             , solution: req.body.solution
             , date_on: Date.now()
           } 
         },
         function(err){ if(err){ 
           console.log(err) 
         } else { 
            console.log('Added')
         }
       });
```